# A warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast using malloc sizeof struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

So I'm getting a `warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast` when trying to create a pointer to a struct.

Struct:

```
typedef struct _book_
{
    char *title;
    char *cat;
    double price;
}Book_T;
```

Code:

```
Book_T *book;
...
if((book = malloc(sizeof(Book_T))) == NULL) return 1;
```

The struct is declared in a different .h file but I double checked that I included it. I'm kinda lost on this one

Comment: What is the data type of the function you code is in?

Comment: ^^ I suspect the function that is in is defined to return a `Book_T*`  and you have code that returns `1` (an `int`).

Comment: ohh yeah... its a void *, that's definitely it, thanks. hmmm this is my first time using pthreads, I guess I can just return NULL, i dont need any special thread function

Comment: If you're failing mallocs, the game's pretty much over anyhow.  I don't ever check for malloc failures and it's never bitten me in such a way that I wish I had.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question with the help of shf301 and Brian, the problem is the actual return type and not anything to do with malloc(). The correct code would be something like:

```
if((book = malloc(sizeof(Book_T))) == NULL) return NULL;
```